# Why does my apache still do nothing after a complete purge and reinstall?

Tags: apt, apache2, lamp

I followed this guide, to the best of my understanding:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

And I'm stuck right after the install.

Here's what I did so far:

- since I already had a working install (which I broke) I thought it was a good idea to start
- List item

  following the instructions at 'Starting over'
- I typed

> **sudo apt-get --purge remove** apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils
>   apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1
>   libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl
>   libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server
>   mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql

- which did something, but then gave error messages about packages not found etc...
- since I wanted to complete this step, **I sudo apt-get --purge remove'd** all packages seperately, and followed through with necessary options.
- as recommended I **sudo rm -r /etc/apache2**'d
- followed by reinstalling **apt-get install apache2**, no errors here
- it now tells me to visit http://localhost to test the installation, which just gives me

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost

I'm at a loss. I managed to configure my apache quite decently but wanted a redo and now I'm stuck even before the real configuration.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen next? If you removed it the error page should be what happens.

Comment: I forgot the vital step of actually doing apt-get install apache2, I'll update my post, sorry :p

Comment: @joon after removal do you start it back up? `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: I'm twice a retard. In my defense, it wasn't mentioned in the page I referred too. It works now.

Comment: @joon It would be helpful if you made an answer on what you did to get it working (we like self documentation!) And then for bonus points, fix the wiki page!

Answer (score 1):

fixed by simply restarting apache.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer (click the check mark) so people know no more help is needed here.

Comment: yeah, there's a waiting time though.